# Beginner: Django dev server external static files

Tags: django

Disclaimer: I am a beginner to Django but have Drupal programming experience.

I have spent some time Googling but can't find the answer to this question: How can I make the Django dev server show images (thumbnails of TIF's in my case) that come from *outside* the STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT of python manage.py runserver 80? For example:

```
# something.html -- a template file -- WORKS AS EXPECTED BUT SEE NEXT EXAMPLE
<img src="http://www.google.com/someDir/someFile.TIF" height="y" width="x">

# BETTER EXAMPLE -- hdrive COMES FROM USB INSERTED AT RUNTIME
<img src="/hdrive/someFile.TIF" height="y" width="x">
```

Thanks!

Comment: You aren't hosting those images, why would your webserver serve them? The users browser will retrieve those thumbnails when the page loads.

Comment: sorry, my example wasn't the best, since yes, that works fine. This is better: <img src="/hdrive/someFile.Tif" height="y" width="x"> when /cdrive/somePath/manage.py (I only know /cdrive at runtime)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't make any sense.

Remember that `<img src=...` is a part of the **rendered** template that is sent to the client's browser. Why would we want the client to be able to fetch any file in any directory they wanted from the server? (i.e.`<a href="/var/db/credit_card_details.sql">download $$$</a>`)

STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT are two designated folders on the server that hold any files we want to be accesible from the outside, i.e. the clients browser.

On the other hand, **before or during rendering** the template (i.e. before the HTML file is sent from the server to the client) we can open files from outside these two directories using [simple python file reading techniques](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

For example, we could open an image saved in a directory outside MEDIA_ROOT or STATIC_ROOT, do something to it and copy the result into the MEDIA_ROOT meaning that the client could then read that file at `/media/copied_file.png`

It seems you are getting confused between the various stages of the request cycle.